# Migrating TFS to new Server

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, database-migration

I am currently working to move TFS from its' current server to a new environment.  My team has already completed the steps as seen in this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware) on moving TFS to a new Server.

We have already installed and migrated/restored our SQL Database in the new server and ensured all the prerequisites for TFS were installed.  The TFS Admin Console is currently installed and we are trying to configure it by using the existing `Tfs_Configure` database.  That all works without a problem, however, when we go to look at our existing Project Collections, the build service is still "linked", having the TFS Address set to the old server and not the one we migrated to.

I have detached the collections in the old environment and reattached them in the new environment, however, they still seem to be trying to build in the old server. I am reading that we needed to detach them prior to migrating any data over. Did we do something incorrectly, or rather, did we try to detach the collections too late into the process?

Comment: I realized there is a 'change urls' command, is it just that simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unregister the build service that uses the `<<oldcomputername>>`. Register a build service with the `<<newcomputername>>`. And do the same for the agent and the controller.

[image]

1. On each build server, open the administration console and stop the
   build service.
2. In the properties for the build service, update the communications
   properties.

[image]

According to the above screenshot, you could see the build service is configured under project collection level.

---

Moreover, for vNext build agent you need to remove and re-configure an agent.

To remove the agent:

```
.\config remove
```

After you've removed the agent, you can [configure it again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows#download-configure).

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your build services to point to the new server. For XAML build, you'll have to reconfigure the build controller. For the modern build system, you'll need to reconfigure your build agent(s).

Comment: Thank you for the response, so if I am understanding you correctly, this has nothing to do with Collections and what instance of TFS Admin Console they are 'attached' to?  I plan on working on this issue tomorrow morning and am just getting prepared.

Comment: In addition, does that mean creating a new Controller/Agent and disabling/deleting the existing ones?